# внести значение переменных в бд mysql

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

пишу бота на php+mysql. но при передаче данных в бд у меня чтото не так.

```
$mysqli->query('INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`name`) VALUES ("$chatId","$name") ');
```

передает 0, $name.
первый у меня `int` а второй `varchar`.
в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('$chatId', '$name')");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка тут

```
$mysqli->query('INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`name`) VALUES ("$chatId","$name") ');
```

Запрос в одинарных кавычках `'`, для того что бы поставлялись параметры php они должны быть в двойных `"`.

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`name`) VALUES ($chatId, '$name')");
```

Или использовать конкатенацию(соединение) строк, так как параметр `$chatId` `int` его можно не экранировать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй имя таблицы обернуть в кавычки

```
 $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO "users"(id,name) VALUES ("$chatId","$name") ');
```

Comment: он с таблицей коннектится. он передает неправильное значение